# How export {} affects declare global

Tags: typescript, node-modules

global.d.ts

```
declare global {
  export interface Window {
    ...
  }

export {}
```

I realized that export {} has an effect on redefining window module.

I saw a brief explanation that export {} makes the d.ts file a module.
However, I didn't understand how d.ts became a module would affect the typescript.
Is there any document that I can refer to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this official documentation of TypeScript, could help you!

> #### Global-modifying Modules
>
> A global-modifying module alters existing values in the global scope when they are imported. For example, there might exist a library which adds new members to String.prototype when imported. This pattern is somewhat dangerous due to the possibility of runtime conflicts, but we can still write a declaration file for it.

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the TypeScript official document below should help.

> *Modules are executed within their own scope, not in the global scope; this means that variables, functions, classes, etc. declared in a module are not visible outside the module unless **they are explicitly exported using one of the export forms**. Conversely, to consume a variable, function, class, interface, etc. exported from a different module, it has to be imported using one of the import forms.
> (source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)*

And the easy explanation of this could be:

> *"We used the export {} line in our global.d.ts file to mark it as an external module. A module is a file that contains at least 1 import or export statement. We are required to do that to be able to augment the global scope."
> (source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-make-types-global)*

> *"If your file does not contain at least 1 import or export statement, it gets treated like a global script file and the isolatedModules setting in your tsconfig.json file forbids this behavior."
> (source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-be-compiled-under-isolatedmodules)*